# php mySQL how to show images, problems on img src

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I've been working on this for four hours and I still have no clue, so I came here to seek help. I'm learning PHP and mySQL and one of the way I learn is to learn from open source projects. Today I'm trying to understand an open source project and I have some problems. Here is the link to the open source project: https://github.com/markpytel/Printstagram  Basically, it has something like the following, let's call it `profileinfo.php` (name of this file is pretty deceiving, it is a page that shows images uploaded by different users)

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT pid,poster, pdate FROM photo WHERE poster='$myusername' OR pid 
in (select pid from tag where taggee='$myusername') OR pid in (select pid 
from ingroup natural join shared where username='$myusername' and username 
!= ownername) ORDER BY pdate desc";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "Posted by: " . $row["poster"].   " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Time: " . $row["pdate"]."<br>";
  // pid is each photo's unique id in the database 
    $pidrow=($row["pid"]);

    ?>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="listsingleREV.php?pidrow=<?php echo $pidrow; ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" id="pidrow" value="View this image" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you click on the button that says "view this image", image uploaded by users will appear. The first question I have is: What's the meaning of the question mark in the image `src`. I understand that there is a PHP tag in the `img src`, but I don't understand why there is a question mark between `listsingleREV.php` and `pidrow`.

`listsingleREV.php` looks like this:

```
<?php  
session_start();    
$pidrow=$_GET['pidrow'];

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("printstagram");
$sql = "SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE pid=$pidrow";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <img src="imageview.php?pid=<?php echo $row["pid"]; ?>" /><br/>
    <?php
}
?>
```

`imageview.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("printstagram") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT image FROM photo WHERE pid=" . $_GET['pid'];
    $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Retrieving Image BLOB<br/>" . mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    header("content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $row["image"];
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Of course, if a user has to click on a button to see each image, it is very inconvenient. So I decide to give myself some practice and modify the code（it is Apache license so I can do it）such that images will be automatically presented on `profileinfo.php` without the need to click on a button. Since `imageview.php` and `listsingleREV.php` show the images, I tried to substitute the form in `profileinfo.php` with these two files. I worked on it for four hours without achieving my goal. Can someone tell me the correct way to show the images on `profileinfo.php` without the need to click on the button?

Comment: `imageview.php?pid=` ..? the question mark there is for HTTP GET parameter..

Comment: As a note, this code base is probably not the best to be learning from. It's using an API that's been deleted from PHP 7 because it was so horrible (`mysql_*`) and is littered with absolutely ridiculous [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you put this up as a public site it can be destroyed in seconds. Have a look at [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for more up-to-date advice on what to do and what to avoid.

Comment: @tadman I was about to comment the same thing...

Comment: If you didn't understand the question mark it means that you need to study the HTML protocol and it verbs before learning php or any other web language.

Comment: Anyway, it's good that you're trying to learn, but this is probably the singular worst example you could have chosen. If you're looking for better examples, have a look at the various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) out there that are supported by a community, not just a one-off weekend hack project someone did as an experiment. As an example, [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is really beginner-friendly environment, it's well documented, and shows you how to properly organize an MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

```
As it appears in imageview.pho the $row[pid] contain the link of your image in photo table so add this line to profileinfo.php under the while loop in the place you want it to display 
 <img src="<?php echo". $row["pid"]."; ?>">
```

Comment: What should the SQL statement before the while loop? profileinfo.php evoke both imageview.php and listsingleREV.php and they have different sql statements.